# How to exclude files from JaCoCo report with Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, jacoco

I am trying to exclude some files in a multi-module Spring Boot project. I tried using the excludes extension from JaCoCo in test as well as adding an afterEvaluate block in jacocoTestReport. Neither of the options has worked. Gradle version is 8.1.1 and Spring Boot version is 3.1.2. Can anyone please help me? Below is the main gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "4.2.1.3168"
}

group = "${group}"
version = "${version}"

subprojects {
    apply {
        plugin "java"
        plugin "org.springframework.boot"
        plugin "io.spring.dependency-management"
        plugin 'jacoco-report-aggregation'
    }

    java {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    dependencies {
        //removed for brevity
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        }
    }

    tasks.named('test') {
        useJUnitPlatform()
//        jacoco {
//            excludes = [
//                    "**/config**"
//            ]
//        }
    }

    bootJar {
        enabled = false
    }

    jacoco {
        toolVersion = "${jacocoVersion}" //0.8.9
    }

    jacocoTestReport {
        reports {
            xml.required = false
            csv.required = false
            html.required = true
        }
    }

    jacocoTestReport {
        dependsOn test

        afterEvaluate {
            classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
                fileTree(dir: it, exclude: [
                        "**/config**"
                ])
            }))
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Perhaps moving to Gradle kts will help more, because it's gonna be fully strongly typed, and then you will have the autocompletion in the IDE. So you will be able to see what is wrong in the properties setup directly in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I added a `testCodeCoverageReport` and `jacocoTestCoverageVerification` tasks to the `build.gradle` and it is working fine now.

I also moved this configuration to the module that contained my test cases as well as the main method.

Updated jacoco config:

```
def jacocoExclude = [
        '**/config/**'
]

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test // tests are required to run before generating the report

    afterEvaluate {
        classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: jacocoExclude)
        }))
    }
}

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    afterEvaluate {
        getClassDirectories().setFrom(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: jacocoExclude)
        })
    }
}

testCodeCoverageReport {
    afterEvaluate {
        getClassDirectories().setFrom(classDirectories.files.collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: jacocoExclude)
        })
    }
}
```